# Why are the bounds of the binomial including 3?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

The following is an extract from a [textbook](https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9781107587434) (17C 6Ciii Extended Response):

> Brett rides his bike to work each day. He knows that the time it takes is **normally distributed** with a **mean of 55** minutes and a **standard deviation of 5** minutes.

$$\therefore X \sim \mathcal{N}(55,5^{2})$$

> During a five-day working week, Brett **makes the ride 10 times**. Find the probability that, in a randomly chosen week, the ride takes **less than 50 minutes more than three times during the week.**

So $Y \sim \mathcal{B}(10,Pr(X<50))$. I thought that the probability of *"less than 50 minutes more than three times during the week"* would be $Pr(Y>3)$, where the bounds are $4$ to $10$. But the book uses the bounds of $3$ to $10$ ($Pr(Y\ge3)$).

Why is $3$ included when the question specifically asks for *more than three times*?

---

Answer from textbook:

> [image: Answer from book]

The textbook has either made a typo on the expression or the answer. The answer in decimal form is $Pr(Y\ge3) = 0.2037$, which is not $Pr(Y>3)$

Comment: The textbook agrees with you perfectly. Did you _see_ correctly?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, yeah you're right. I've added some more explanation. Now I'm just wondering weather it's $Pr(Y\ge3) = 0.2037$ or $Pr(Y>3)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's either a typo or a mistake in the book.

Indeed, the statement $\Pr(X>3) = 1-\Pr(X\leq 2)$ is not true.